# MultiIndex column names and pandas styler alignment

Tags: pandas, multi-index, pandas-styles

In Jupyter, when displaying a DataFrame with a `MultiIndex`, the first level is left-aligned.

```
import numpy as np
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x, y) for x in ['A', 'B', 'C'] for y in ['O', 'I']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 6), index=['n', 'm'], columns=cols)
df
```

[image: multiindex left-aligned]

When displaying the same using pandas styler, it becomes right-aligned, however:

```
df.style
```

[image: multiindex pandas styler right-aligned]

How can I control the alignment?

Comment: I noticed since the upgrade to Notebook 7 that my dataframe multi-index columns are now right-aligned by default.  Has anyone else noticed this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* the difference is, but here's a simple fix:

```
style = df.style.set_table_styles([
   {'selector': 'th',
    'props': [
        ('text-align', 'left')
    ]
    }]
)

style
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking to see if this can be set as a global option but can't find an equivalent option using `pd.describe_option()`.  I'm guessing there isn't one.  Anyone know?